# HP laptop doesn't recover from shutting the lid in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: suspend, laptop

I am just about finished setting up this new HP 15s-er1004AU laptop with 20.04.

However, when I shut the lid then open a bit later, I see a blank black screen.

I watch and wait. Nothing.

I press space. Nothing.

I press the on switch. Nothing.

Finally, I hold down the off switch for a few seconds. Ubuntu reboots and I can log in.

On my older Samsung laptop (Ubu 18.04), when I open the lid after a few minutes or a few hours, I get the login screen, type my password and Ubuntu is up and running again.

This happens on the new laptop too, if I just leave it alone: screen goes black, but touch a button and the log in screen appears.

But not when the lid has been closed.

Is there something I can do about this problem? Any tips please?

Following other threads here, I tried:

pedro@pedro-HP:~$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
GPP1      S4    *disabled
GP17      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.1
GPP0      S4    *disabled
pedro@pedro-HP:~$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for pedro:
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for pedro:
root@pedro-HP:/home/pedro# echo "LID" > /proc/acpi/wakeup
root@pedro-HP:/home/pedro# exit
exit
pedro@pedro-HP:~$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
GPP1      S4    *disabled
GP17      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.1
GPP0      S4    *disabled
pedro@pedro-HP:~$

I don't know what GPP1 or GPP0 are or how I might enable them on this HP laptop!

I can't find anything with HP or LID in /sys/devices/platform except a folder called hp-wmi.

Anyone know where I might set S4 to "enabled" on this HP??